# Debugging utilities for Linux process hang issues?

Tags: linux, process, freeze

I have a daemon process which does the configuration management. all the other processes should interact with this daemon for their functioning. But when I execute a large action, after few hours the daemon process is unresponsive for 2 to 3 hours. And After 2- 3 hours it is working normally.

Debugging utilities for Linux process hang issues?

How to get at what point the linux process hangs?

Answer (score 11):

- strace can show the last system calls and their result
- lsof can show open files
- the system log can be very effective when log messages are written to track progress. Allows to box the problem in smaller areas. Also correlate log messages to other messages from other systems, this often turns up interesting results
- wireshark if the apps use sockets to make the wire chatter visible.
- ps ax + top can show if your app is in a busy loop, i.e. running all the time, sleeping or blocked in IO, consuming CPU, using memory.

Each of these may give a little bit of information which together build up a picture of the issue.

When using gdb, it might be useful to trigger a core dump when the app is blocked. Then you have a static snapshot which you can analyze using post mortem debugging at your leisure. You can have these triggered by a script. The you quickly build up a set of snapshots which can be used to test your theories.

Comment: I don't think `ps ax` is a good utility for detecting busy loops, `top` would do better for this

Comment: You are right of course, I tend to use these almost always side by side, so they got mixed up in my head. thanks, I updated the answer

Comment: Hi Peter,

strace helped me to troubleshoot the hang issue.

The hang is because of a deadlock scenario between two processes for a file lock using 'flock()'.

Thank you very much for the help. Without strace it is really an impossible task to find out why the process is hanging.

Comment: I am glad my answer was helpful. You might consider accepting the answer then your acceptance ratio goes up which makes people more likely to help you, and I get the 15 points of course ;-).

Comment: @PeterTillemans, So how do I look last system calls using strace if the process hangs? Looks like strace is only able to show calls being done when it listens the process

Comment: @MaxLobur you can attach strace to a running process by passing the process id with the -p option. But when it is hanging it is quite possible that it is in a tight loop in the code or blocked in an io call, neither will show any output. In that case the debugger needs to be dusted off.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `gdb` and use the `attach` command in order to attach to a running process. You will need to load a file containing the symbols of the executable in question (using the `file` command)

Comment: You can also do this straight from the command line with `gdb /path/to/executable PID`

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to do:

1. Listening on a UNIX domain socket, to handle status requests. An external application can then inquire as to whether the application is still ok. If it gets no response within some timeout period, then it can be assumed that the application being queried has deadlocked or is dead.
2. Periodically touching a file with a preselected path. An external application can look a the timestamp for the file, and if it is stale, then it can assume that the appliation is dead or deadlocked.
3. You can use the `alarm` syscall repeatedly, having the signal terminate the process (use sigaction accordingly). As long as you keep calling `alarm` (i.e. as long as your program is running) it will keep running. Once you don't, the signal will fire.

You can seamlessly restart your process as it dies with `fork` and `waitpid` as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538587/how-to-protect-my-process-from-being-killed/6538718#6538718). It does not cost any significant resources, since the OS will share the memory pages.